# menu does not close when clicking the links

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

Personal made a site onepage is in this [link](http://agenciafront.com.br/oburguer/), it has a fixed menu on the side that opens when it is clicked by it is the following in these links there are anchors that when they are clicked the site usually descends however the menu does not close when clicking the link the idea is that close follows some of my code you can see the problem by accessing the [link](http://agenciafront.com.br/oburguer/).

Toggle JS:

```
class ShapeOverlays {
    constructor(elm) {
        this.elm = elm;
        this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
        this.numPoints = 2;
        this.duration = 600;
        this.delayPointsArray = [];
        this.delayPointsMax = 0;
        this.delayPerPath = 200;
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.isOpened = false;
        this.isAnimating = false;
    }
    toggle() {
        this.isAnimating = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
            this.delayPointsArray[i] = 0;
        }
        if (this.isOpened === false) {
            this.open();
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
    }
    open() {
        this.isOpened = true;
        this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.renderLoop();
    }
    close() {
        this.isOpened = false;
        this.elm.classList.remove('is-opened');
        this.timeStart = Date.now();
        this.renderLoop();
    }
    updatePath(time) {
        const points = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
            const thisEase = this.isOpened ?
                    (i == 1) ? ease.cubicOut : ease.cubicInOut :
                    (i == 1) ? ease.cubicInOut : ease.cubicOut;
            points[i] = thisEase(Math.min(Math.max(time - this.delayPointsArray[i], 0) / this.duration, 1)) * 100
        }

        let str = '';
        str += (this.isOpened) ? `M 0 0 V ${points[0]} ` : `M 0 ${points[0]} `;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints - 1; i++) {
            const p = (i + 1) / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100;
            const cp = p - (1 / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100) / 2;
            str += `C ${cp} ${points[i]} ${cp} ${points[i + 1]} ${p} ${points[i + 1]} `;
        }
        str += (this.isOpened) ? `V 0 H 0` : `V 100 H 0`;
        return str;
    }
    render() {
        if (this.isOpened) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
                this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * i)));
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
                this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - i - 1))));
            }
        }
    }
    renderLoop() {
        this.render();
        if (Date.now() - this.timeStart < this.duration + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - 1) + this.delayPointsMax) {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                this.renderLoop();
            });
        } else {
            this.isAnimating = false;
        }
    }
}

(function () {
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (overlay.isAnimating) {
            return false;
        }
        overlay.toggle();
        if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
            elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
            }
        } else {
            elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: can you not just use `this.toggle()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no href's in any of the anchor tags so nothing is happening. Are these meant to be links or are you trying to perform some animations when they are clicked?

If anchor hrefs are okay try adding a little JavaScript. I'm just recycling the code that you are using but instead of adding the event listener to .hamburger add it to gNavItems and remove the lines that you don't need.

```
(function () {
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    $('.global-menu__item').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click' , function(){
            if (overlay.isAnimating) {
                return false;
            }
            overlay.toggle();
            elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
            }
        });
    });

}());
```

Comment: friend actually has yes but I left an anchor that is the second that is called chef cadu if you click you will realize that it goes down to session plus the menu does not close and when you open the console with the menu open you will realize that it generates a class called is-opened-navi needed to sort out a way to remove it, believing that removing it by cycling the link normally closes the menu.

Comment: @Kirito Okay, I can see now that the scroll bit is working when chef cadu is clicked. I'm just going to try and recycle a little bit of your code to see if we can achieve what you want. I'll edit my answer and you'll see it there.